# Option Search Bar in html that searches using different attributes

Tags: php, html

I want to make a search bar in a table called items with two different options: `IID`, `Type`. The code is below.

```
<h1> Search </h1>
   <form name="search" action="items.php" method="get">
     Search For: <input type="text" name="item"> in
     <select name = "Option">
       <option value= "IID"> IID </option>
       <option value= "Type"> Type </option>
     </select>
   <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

The data is stored as a table called Item with attributes IID and type. 
I then do a query, but I'm getting lost here on how to change the select clause.

I have the code here so that it searches for item(s) with a certain type the user inputs, but how can I also change the clause so that it corresponds to the option menu in the search bar where you can find items with IID? Would I have to write 2 different queries?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php

//SEARCH by type
    $item = ucfirst($_GET["item"]);
    if($item != null){
        $result = executePlainSQL("select * from item where type = '" . $item . "'");
    }
    else{
        $result = executePlainSQL("select * from item");
    }
     printItem_byType($result);

//Print result  
function printItem_byType($result){
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><td>IID</td><td>Type</td></tr>';
    while ($row = OCI_Fetch_Array($result, OCI_BOTH)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
            <td><a href = profile.php?IID=" . $row[1] . ">" . $row[1] . "</a></td>
            <td><a href= profile.php?type= ". $row[2] . ">" $row[2] . "</td></tr>";                             
    }
    echo '</table>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//SEARCH by type
$item = ucfirst($_GET["item"]);
$option = $_GET["option"];
if($item != null){
    $result = executePlainSQL("select * from item where type = '" . $item . "' and filter_by = '" . $option . "'");
}
else{
    $result = executePlainSQL("select * from item");
}
```

then add one colum called "filter_by" on the sql table.